# Alexa account linking - How to store more than access token

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

When I link an account with a third party they send an access token as well as the user's username.

Alexa automatically saves the access token and gives it with each request. How can I get it to save the username as well?

Comment: This is not possible AFIK.

Answer (score 1):

This is intentionally not supported in order to protect the user's privacy. That is a good thing.

Alexa does provide a userID with each call. This id is specific to each user, and the same every time they use your skill. It doesn't give you any personal information, but it does allow you to save information for each user to your own database. You can associate that user's data with the userId and recall it every time they use your skill.

So for example, you can ask the user for a name, save it to your database keyed by the userId, and recall it at a later date using the userId.

Search on "alexa user information" for more info, for example [this post](https://forums.developer.amazon.com/questions/5637/how-to-get-user-name-from-alexa-skill.html).

Answer (score 1):

Just encode the user name and/or any other information to the token itself.

For example you can use  JSON Web Token - https://jwt.io/ - wich is an [RFC 7519](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc7519)

It is intended exactly for the use case when you you don't want to make an additional request(s) just to retrieve some rarely changing info.

Regards caching/refreshing you can issue token for limited amount of time (*an hour?*).